# spyder kernel dies during training

Tags: python, pytorch, spyder

I am trying to train an fairly complex GCN network on my 10GB GPU. It runs smoothly until epoch 87 but then the spyder kernel restarts. Is it because of memory issue, if so how can I handle it.

Comment: Reduce some of the parameters to lower the memory size. If you are outputting and saving any computations, make sure to detach them from the GPU. In PyTorch it is akin to: `x.detach().cpu().numpy()`

Comment: so if I detach is that mean it will be cleared from gpu. Thanks will try it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, If the model is too large it good to store logs after every epoch.

```
## after every epoch
path = os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, 'model.pth')
torch.save(TheModelClass.cpu().state_dict(), path) # saving model
MODEL.cuda() # moving model to GPU for further training

## if the kernel terminates, load the model paramters
device = torch.device("cuda")
model = TheModelClass()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.train()
model.to(device)
```

so, anything happens at the process you can start from the last completed epoch. 
from your information, it's hard to tell what is the causes to terminate the kernel exactly. RAM overloading is less likely because of GPU acceleration and using `pytorch` framework. but it could be.
However, the above solution will help you anywhere.

Comment: yes I did save my model so I didn't need to start from scratch but did not do the same for losses and accuracies. Now logging everything so that at least I have an idea what was happening untill it stops. Thanks